# In HTML, what is the attribute ' is="Weedle" '

Tags: html, attributes

What is the 'is=' attribute?
What is the Weedle?

I found these on an API and when I google them I get 'What is HTML' and 'Pokemon #13'

I know that weedle may just be a name but it's written elsewhere on the site like its a common term.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `is` attribute is a feature of Custom Elements; it’s for assigning a custom element name to a [“customized built-in element” created by extending an existing element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#custom-elements-core-concepts:custom-element):

> Two distinct types of custom elements can be defined:
>
> 1. An *autonomous custom element*, which is defined with no `extends` option. These types of custom elements have a local name equal to their defined name.
> 2. A *customized built-in element*, which is defined with an `extends` option. These types of custom elements have a local name equal to the value passed in their `extends` option, and **their defined name is used as the value of the *`is`* attribute**.

So presumably in the HTML you’re looking at, the `is="Weedle"` attribute is being used to create a new *`Weedle`* custom element based on whatever existing built-in element it’s being used with.